# Can I lend my car to a friend and leave my handgun under the seat in a cabled lockbox?

Tags: firearms, michigan

I’m in Michigan, I have a permit to carry a concealed weapon, and I keep it in a combination lockbox under the driver seat. The lockbox is cabled to the seat. Is it legal for a friend or family member (who does not have a permit to carry a concealed weapon) to drive  that car (assuming they do not know the combination to the lockbox)?